# Why does Electron's desktopCapturer return nothing (under the JSON tree), which causes a crash on my program?

Tags: javascript, electron, desktopcapturer

I tried to use `desktopCapturer` in Electron, but when I tried to fetch all available sources, it returns a null value in all of those sources. Here, I got an example of 4 sources displaying in the JSON tree, but it came up with no name. Here is the image of the JSON tree from the console.

[image]

As you can see, the `name` field is empty. When this happens, I often get a crash that I couldn't find the name of the sources. Here is the code when it's handy to solve the problem.

```js
const { desktopCapturer } = require('@electron/remote');

const StartCapture = async () => {
  const AppSources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['screen', 'window'] });
  console.log(AppSources)
  const SelSource = AppSources.find(Source => Source.name === 'Screen Name');
  
  if (!SelSource) {
    console.error('Screen source not found');
    return;
  }
  
  const VideoRenderer = document.createElement('video');
  VideoRenderer.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: SelSource.id,
        minWidth: 960,
        maxWidth: 2560,
        minHeight: 480,
        maxHeight: 1440
      }
    }
  });
  
  VideoRenderer.play();
  
  const CanvasRenderer = document.getElementById('canvas-renderer');
  const CanvasCTX = CanvasRenderer.getContext('2d');
  
  setInterval(() => {
    CanvasCTX.drawImage(VideoRenderer, 0, 0, CanvasRenderer.width, CanvasRenderer.height);
  }, 1000 / 60);
};

document.getElementById('ui-start-capture').addEventListener('click', StartCapture);
```

In the entry side, I have already enabled the `@electron/remote` module. Here is a snippet.

```js
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()
    require('@electron/remote/main').enable(UIWindow.webContents)
```

Can anyone please help me on how to fix this problem? Thanks.